# Call Cortana API from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cortana

I wanted to know if there is a way to use the microsoft's cortana api from a web application. Basically to use speech to text for entering text into an input box and do some operations on that. I had tried using the javascript WebSpeechAPI toobut its only for chrome i guess. Any info on the use of cortana api or any other alternatives for a .NET web app will be helpful.

### What i found so far -

I know that cortana is supported on UWP (universal windows platform) apps.. so was wondering if there could be a hack to create an api which i could call from the client to invoke cortana and get my work done. there is also a github repo that makes use of a meta tag pointing to a VCD (voice command definition) config file but not sure how to make use of that.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Check here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana The information will be here...

Also they have examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Comment: From what I can tell, there's no way to invoke Cortana from a web page. There's Bing APIs you can use, which allow voice search and the like. That's pretty much what Cortana is doing anyways.

Comment: In particular for your use case: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api

Comment: @Niels I was looking for more of a call from a web application and not a WUP app..I had gone through the links you had sent, before, but could not find anything related to web applications there.. but thanks for your inputs anyway..

Comment: @ChrisPratt  - thanks, I was going in the direction of bing API as well but have to investigate further on that. My intention was to know if theoretically, it is possible to make a wrapper around, say a WUP app which can talk to cortana and expose it as an adapter/service for a web app to consume or interact with. I don't have much knowledge on WUP apps so not sure if I am making any sense at all. Also, we are talking about a web app where different browsers/environments/platforms come into picture. Your thoughts ?

Comment: Well there's the concept of intents, where essentially certain URLs are interpreted as belonging to certain apps. I think pretty much every mobile platform has some version of this concept, but they don't necessarily all work the same. It also, of course, requires that the app you're tying to target 1) is capable of accepting intents and 2) actually supports doing the thing you want to do via an intent.

Comment: An example is like when you go to login via Facebook and the actual Facebook app, rather than just the website loads. That's the Facebook app accepting an intent to do a login and taking over.

Comment: I understand, but I wouldn't call mine an app so not sure how the intent thing fits here. Basically it would be a voice command service that I am looking for which would invoke Cortana when I call it from the web page (using a mic. button). More like the Google voice search (which uses the HTML5 WebSpeech API). The reason I brought WUP app is because as right now Cortana can be used only through that platform (please correct me if I am wrong) so my idea was to make that dummy app behave like a service which in turn can be exposed to a web application as a reference.